# Why DjangoRF serializer is_valid is false?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

My class

```
class SprintSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    links = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Sprint
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'end', 'links', )
```

In my shell,I populated a serializer with data

```
serializer = SprintSerializer(data=({'name':'JHolmes','description':'ambassador','end':'2019-01-27T15:17:10.375877'}))
```

Then

```
serializer.data
{'name': 'JHolmes', 'description': 'ambassador', 'end': '2019-01-27T15:17:10.375877'}
serializer.validated_data
{}
serializer.is_valid()
False
```

Why is an instance serializer False?
EDIT
As Berry pointed out,data format was wrong

```
serializer.errors
{'end': [ErrorDetail(string='Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY[-MM[-DD]].', code='invalid')]}
```

Solved issue

```
'end':'2019-01-27'
serializer.is_valid()
True
```

Comment: and what in the `serializer.errors`?

Comment: yes,data format was wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use below code to find out validation errors:

```
print(serializer.errors)
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue and as I saw in the previusly comments, after serializer.is_valid() line, you can write the next one code: 'print(serializer.errors)'. Which bring you information from the console about why your serialize model is failling. A way you could find the info could be:

```
if not serializer.is_valid():
   print(serializer.errors)
```